# Preventing Spurious Watch Output Between Modules in Perl Debugger

Tags: perl, debugging

Using `perl -d`, I set a watch (`w $myVar`) on a variable used in my script. Whenever my script calls to a perl module, the watch "resets" to an undefined value.

```
Watchpoint 0:   $myVar changed:
    old value:  'foo_part_1'
    new value:  ''
Net::FTP::cwd(/usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/Net/FTP.pm:548):
548:     @_ == 1 || @_ == 2 or croak 'usage: $ftp->cwd( [ DIR ] )';
__DB<2> r
scalar context return from Net::FTP::cwd: 1
Watchpoint 0:   $myVar changed:
    old value:  ''
    new value:  'foo_part_1'
```

Is is possible to suppress either;
(1) The change messages that stem from the scope change in perl. Or;

(2) The entire execution output of the module? In most cases, I didn't write it, and I'm pretty sure I can't debug it, so I really don't care to see it's line by line execution in 95%+ of cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can work around this by using `$myVar` as a global or a package variable and then "watching" it's fully qualified name:

```
package MyPackage;
use strict;
...
use vars qw($myVar);
...
```

or

```
package MyPackage;
our $myVar = 'foo_part_1';
...
```

and then watching it with `w $MyPackage::myVar`:

Comment: And, just because I'm curious, there's no similar syntax without declaring a package? Something like `w filename.pl::$myVar`?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/package.html has a sentence that caught my eye. `If package name is omitted, the main package as assumed. That is, $::sail is equivalent to $main::sail`. Does that mean with modification that I could put your suggestion to use, and use `w $main::myVar`? Or does it mean that I'd have to put `package` at the top of my script, but don't necessarily have to put a name with it?